# Questions about Scale Factor?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We have a final study guide for our geometry class and we never learned anything about scale factor so we were just wondering if anyone could help explain any of the questions. One of the people in our group said that it's just the measure of the side of one shape over the side of the other shape inside, since the shapes we're given are all shapes with equal sides, so the proportions between the inside and outside shapes would be the same. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image: scale_factor_questions]

Comment: I think Question 13 could've been worded a little better, the 2nd triangle _circumscribes_ the circle. (maybe this is a typo?)

Comment: The scale factor here must be the ratio of the length of one side of the triangle (square,n-gon) to the length of one side of the other triangle (square,n-gon).

Comment: Any two *similar figures* are said to have a "scale factor" that relates the size of one to the other by a constant ratio.  For example, any two equilateral triangles are similar, and any two circles are similar.